# Are there any standard for build_info.json?

Tags: docker, building

I see many projects uses `build_info.json`, but I can't find documentation for that file. Is it used by something? Is it a de-facto standard? Who is using it, and who provides? Are there any expectations on it's content?

Comment: It's not a standard Docker thing, for what it's worth.  Do you have an example of how you might use it?

Comment: People want to save build information (which commit was used, etc) and there is 'build_info.json' appears in many places. `conan` does it, npm does, etc. I wondered if there is some kind of common ground for those files.